# Postman hangs while i make post request. Post request Working fine for registration but not for login

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, postman, passport-jwt

So i am implementing basic login/registration using passportJs JWT. Framework i am using is express of node.js. Problem is i am registering a user, it is working fine as it registers via Postman and i can see it in mongodb shell using `db.users.find()`. But when i am making a POST request to authenticate user means login it is giving me "User not Found" when i change JSON(application/json) to Text. Otherwise it hangs and after some time terminates.

app.js

```
   const app = express();

   const users = require('./routes/users');

   //port
   const port = 3000;

   //middleware
   app.use(cors());

   //Front
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

   //middleware
   app.use(bodyParser.json());

   app.use(passport.initialize());
   app.use(passport.session());

   require('./config/passport')(passport);
```

passport.js

```
module.exports = function(){
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
    opts.secretOrKey = 'secret';
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts , (jwt_payload, done) => {
        User.getUserById(jwt_payload._id, (err, user) =>{
            if(err){
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if(user){
                return done(null, user);
            }
            else{
                return done(null, false);
            }
        })
    }));
}
```

users.js

```
router.post('/authenticate', (req,res,next) =>{
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.getUserByemail(email, (err, user) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!user){
            return res.json({success: false,msg:'user Not Found'});
        }
        User.comparePassword(password,user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if(err){
                if(isMatch()){
                    const token = jwt.sign(user,'secret', {
                        expiresIn: 86400 // 1 Day
                    });
                    res.json({
                        success: true,
                        token: 'JWT ' +token,
                        user:{
                            id: user._id,
                            name: user.fname+ ' ' + user.lname,
                            email: user.email
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    return res.json({success: false,msg:'Wrong Password'});
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

user.js

```
module.exports.getUserByemail = function(email, callback){
    const query = {email: email}
    User.findOne(query,callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see with your code, passport has nothing to do with your error since your `/authenticate` route is public (not using the passport middleware), so we can take this out of the equation.

I would suggest to double check/log the `req.body` and see if you are getting the right information in your API function, I'm pretty sure the data is wrong especially  since you are talking about the request format text/json.

Comment: I have checked `req.body` it is giving me the desired information which i have posted thorugh postman. The error is in `comparePassword()` or `if(!user){}` i think.

Comment: Can you show the console.log of the req.body please?

Comment: `Server Started 3000`

`Connected to database`

`{ email: 'asif@gmail.com', password: '1234' }`